# SQL move data from rows to cols

Tags: sql, self-join

Sorry for the bad title - I simply do not know what to call the thing I want to do.

Here it goes:

In MS SQL Server 2008

I have a temp table with 4000+ rows created with the WITH statement looking like this:

ID (varchar)    DATE (int)

AB1135000097  |  20151221
AB1135000097  |  20160119
AB1135000097  |  20160219
AB1135001989  |  20120223
AB1135001989  |  20120323
AB1135001989  |  20120423
.
.
.

I want to pair the data in date-ranges based on DATE.

AB1135000097  |  20151221    |   20160119
AB1135000097  |  20160119    |   20160219
AB1135001989  |  20120223    |   20120323
AB1135001989  |  20120323    |   20120423

Does this action have a name ? (I will add tags to the post when I know what I'm asking for)

Comment: Could you explain a little bit more ? What are the letters and numbers representing ? What exactly do you want ? A little context might help.

Comment: Suppose there was also a row `A 5` in the table?  What should the output be?  Are you looking to combine adjacent numbers, or just nearest neighbour values?  Also, why don't you give your table a name and the columns a name?  If we're meant to write SQL, we need that information!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem. Inspired by Jonathan Leffler's solution. Thanks a lot!

It is based on adding row-numbers to the table ordered by ID and DATE, and then self-join with ROW+1 to get the next date as a second date column.

```
with 
SCHEDULE as
( -- remove duplicates and NULL entries

    select DISTINCT ID, DATE from TABLE1
    where DATE IS NOT NULL
),

SCHEDULE_WITH_ROW as
(
select * from (
    select DISTINCT ROW_NUMBER()
        OVER (ORDER BY ID, DATE) AS
        ROW, ID, DATE 
    from SCHEDULE) AS SCHED
)

select 
    S1.ID
    , S1.DATE
    , S2.DATE
from SCHEDULE_WITH_ROW S1
    join SCHEDULE_WITH_ROW S2 on S2.ID = S1.ID and S1.ROW + 1 = S2.ROW
```

Answer (score 4):

#### Assumed schema

I am assuming that your table is like:

```
CREATE TABLE "TABLE"
(
    tag     CHAR(1) NOT NULL,
    value   INTEGER NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(tag, value)
);
```

I really shouldn't have to guess the schema though.

#### Possible answer

Superficially, you might be after:

```
SELECT t1.tag, t1.value, t2.value
  FROM "TABLE" AS t1
  JOIN "TABLE" AS t2
    ON t1.tag = t2.tag AND t2.value = t1.value + 1
 ORDER BY t1.tag, t1.value;
```

This joins the table with itself, combining rows where the `tag` column values (`A`, `B`, ...) are the same, and where the `value` column in one row is one more than the `value` column in the other.

On the other hand, if you add a row `('A', 5)` to the table and expect it to appear in the output as part of a row `('A', 3, 5)`, then the query is much harder to write without using OLAP features.

Comment: like this answer .. 
according to given example this answer is very correct.

Answer (score 1):

if you are using Oracle database then you can refer following query to solve this question -

```
with t as
(
SELECT 'A' Col1, 1 Col2
  FROM Dual
UNION ALL
SELECT 'A' Col1, 2 Col2
  FROM Dual
UNION ALL
SELECT 'A' Col1, 3 Col2
  FROM Dual
UNION ALL
SELECT 'B' Col1, 4 Col2
  FROM Dual
UNION ALL
SELECT 'B' Col1, 5 Col2
  FROM Dual
UNION ALL
SELECT 'B' Col1, 6 Col2 FROM Dual
)
SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT Col1,
               Col2,
               Lead(Col1) Over(ORDER BY Col1, Col2) Col3,
               Lead(Col2) Over(ORDER BY Col1, Col2) Col4
          FROM t  --(your table name)
         ORDER BY Col1, Col2)
 WHERE Col1 = Col3
```

as I don't have your table name and table structure I have created one temp table in Query itself.

you need to change  `From t` to `From` with your table name . .. please change col1 and col2 column name also accordingly.