# how to convert rows to columns in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a Table

```
F1      F2
-----------------
name    Happy
Company a
City    Gurgaon
name    Deepak
Company b
City    Delhi
```

I need the output as -

```
name    company   city
-----------------------    
Happy     a       Gurgaon
Deepak    b       Delhi
```

I am using the query

```
SELECT
   CASE WHEN F1='name'
    THEN F2 ELSE NULL END) AS name,
   CASE WHEN F1='Company'
     THEN F2 ELSE NULL END) AS Company,
   CASE WHEN F1='City'
     THEN F2 ELSE NULL END) AS city
FROM table1
```

but I am getting the output as :

```
name    company      city
-----------------------------
Happy       
          a 
                Gurgaon
Deepak      
          b 
                Delhi
```

Can someone help please? I do not want to use `PIVOT`. Can this be achieved using inner join

Comment: you can do it using pivot 
try the answer in given link 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15745042/efficiently-convert-rows-to-columns-in-sql-server

Comment: I want to do this with self join

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11311549/sql-move-data-from-rows-to-cols

Comment: Do you have some sort of column or value that shows that `Happy`, `a` and `Gurgaon` all belong in the same row?  Right now you aren't showing any way to associate the values into the same row.

Comment: ok..U are right.. I will try by adding a new column with values like - 1,1,1,2,2,2

Answer (score 0):

Create a table to insert the elements with identity field

```
CREATE TABLE #TEMP(ID INT IDENTITY(1,1), F1 VARCHAR(20), F2 VARCHAR(20))

INSERT INTO #TEMP
SELECT * FROM
(
 SELECT 'name' F1,    'Happy'  F2
 UNION ALL
 SELECT 'Company', 'a'
 UNION ALL
 SELECT 'City',    'Gurgaon'
 UNION ALL
 SELECT 'name',    'Deepak'
 UNION ALL
 SELECT 'Company', 'b'
 UNION ALL
 SELECT 'City',    'Delhi'
)TAB
```

Since you don't have an Id for each set, we need to generate separate `Id` after every 3 records
and pivot according to that `Id`.

```
SELECT name, Company,City
FROM 
(
       -- Generate seperate Id after every 3 records
       SELECT F1,F2,CAST((ID/3.5)AS INT)+1 RNO  
       FROM #TEMP
)P
PIVOT(MIN(F2)
      FOR F1 IN (name, Company,City)) AS PVTTable
```

**RESULT**

[image]